# MySQL - Increasing limit by 1 results increases execution time from less than a second to infinite

Tags: mysql, infinite

Using a simple query like:

`select * from <table> limit 5;`

will return results in a fraction of a second, which is expected. I can increase the limit up to 49, and the results will still be returned within a fraction of a second. Increasing the limit to 50, however, will result in an infinite execution time.

Selecting only one column allows me to increase the limit up to a few thousand, but the same issue applies when I limit the query to around 5000.

I'm using a database with roughly 100 columns and 22 million rows.

Why am I seeing this behaviour?

Edit:

Using an "order by":

`select * from <table> order by id limit 5;` 57 seconds

`select * from <table> order by id limit 50;` 57 seconds

`select * from <table> order by id limit 100;` did not finish

Comment: The big question is how many rows?

Comment: @Mihai around 22 million

Comment: Any indexes on the table?

Comment: Im guessing that the mysql optimizer wont count all the rows when you dont use order by if the percentage of rows returned with limit is very low,it will grab the first rows it gets his hands on.Pass a threshold and the optimizer will decide to do a table scan even if there is no order by.That threshold might be a data quantity rather than the number of rows.This is just a guess,I might be wrong

Comment: @mathielo yes, two columns for IDs are indexed

Comment: @Mihai adding an order by `select * from <table> order by id limit 5;` took about 50 seconds, and I'm concerned that increasing the limit will take even longer.

Comment: Play with the limit in ORDER BY ,edit your question with your findings.

Comment: You might want to try http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What question? What was the question? This looks more like a status report to me. (Questions would be more like: Why am I seeing this behavior? Is there a way to see the execution plan for the query? Can I influence the behavior of the optimizer? There's answers to those questions, but there's no suitable answer for a question you didn't ask.

Comment: @spencer7593 I'm sorry, asking the question itself must have slipped my mind while typing out the pertinent information. I'm wondering why I'm seeing this behaviour, and how I can decrease the execution time.

Comment: I think there is a time parameter in mysql after which a query expires,but I forgot the name.

Comment: Are you using the *mysql* client? and possibly with the `-q` option? Some problems have been reported when using `mysql -q` on Ubuntu (eg, try `desc <table>;`).

Comment: @ring0 I'm using MySQL Workbench. I don't think I'm using the `-q` option,  but just in case, how do I check?

Comment: Try using the mysql client, do the same query (without the `-q` option of course), and see if you get the same behavior - hopefully no - the problem would be located at Workbench.

Comment: @ring0 using PuTTY, the query with the `limit 100` took the same amount of time as the others with lowers limits. Workbench must have been causing the issues!

Answer (score 0):

This may be of help:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Try using `SQL_BIG_RESULT` or `SQL_BUFFER_RESULT`.

This may also be due to a poor memory allocation setting.
Are you storing BLOB's or any other large fields?